# C Linux - How to execute program from another program

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, exec, fork

I am trying to execute program (let's call that program2) that I wrote from another program.

I compile program2 and have executable file call `client`.

I want to run program2 and for that I create process `fork` for trying to execute program2 by using the `exec` function.

The program needs two arguments run.

I use:

```
execvp("client",arguments)
```

Where `arguments` is a `NULL`-terminated `char*`-array, and `arguments[0]` is `"client"`. The program fails in the `exec` operation with error `No Such File Or Directory`.

In other words, how do I run my code from another program using the `exec` function?

code:

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

```
struct Integrals* shm_ptr; 
key_t key;      
int i,status;
int shm_id;
pid_t pid;  
int child_pid[PROCESS];
char  curPid[10];
int curpid;
double calcSegment[SIZE];
int from,to;
double segment;

curpid=getpid();
sprintf(curPid,"%d",curpid);

char* arguments[]={"client",argv[1],curPid,NULL};

signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);//"install" the 'sig_handler' func in case ^C signl.

printf("---------->%s",arguments[0]);
key=ftok("\tmp",(char)argv[1][0]);

if( (shm_id=shmget(key,sizeof(Integrals),IPC_CREAT|0600))==-1)
{
    perror("Fail To Allocate Shared Memory");
    exit(1);
}


if((shm_ptr=(Integrals*)shmat(shm_id,NULL,0))<0)
{
    perror("Fail To Attach Memory");
    exit(1);

}


pid=fork();

if(pid<0)
{
    perror("The Fork Failed");
    exit(1);    
}

else if(pid==0)
{
    if(execvp("workspace/hafala/EX2/client",arguments)==-1)
    {
        perror("Faile To Execute 'client.c' Program");
        exit(1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why does the program fail? Check errno.

Comment: the program fail in "No Such File Or Directory"

Comment: give us a `strace -s 200 -f -o ./program1` output...

Comment: Do you have a program called `client` in your PATH?

Comment: The client is an exectubale file that located in the same directory of the current program(the program that trying to run the program)         what path i need to add ? and how?

Comment: The functions execlp and execvp will duplicate the actions of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified file name does not contain a slash (/) character. The search path is the path specified in the environment by the PATH variable. If this variable isn't specified, the default path ``:/bin:/usr/bin'' is used. In addition, certain errors are treated specially.

Comment: try giving the full file path of "client" executable.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-adding-path/

Comment: Do i need to copy the long srting that return from echo $PATH??

Comment: I try run execvp(".",arguments)                                         and now the error is "permission Denied"                                    i saw that '.' is going to the cureent PATH online

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the external program with the full path instead of just the exec name.

It looks like a very simple problem of relocation of the executable file.

At least I would check there. Another solution is to move the client application in the same directory of the caller of change the current directory context.

Comment: The client program is in the same directory.                                   because of that i use execvp(".",arguments)                                   now the problem is "Permission Denied"                                   I tried do on program 2 "chmod +x client" but still same erroe of permission

Comment: Permission denied could depend on the fact that the user running the process you are developing is not able to "read" the called (client) program. Eventually try with a chmod o+r or make sure your user is the owner of part of the group owner.

Comment: This is The permissiond that i have by run ls - l:                                                                                                        prog 1:(from her i trying to run prog 2):                                  -rwxrwxr-x 1                                                                    prog 2:(the client)                                                          -rwxr-xr-x 1

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, have you tried to call it as execvp("./client",arguments) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the 1st parameter which is not matched with the program you specified

Try copying the **client** executable file to the same directory and change the code to this.

```
char* arguments[]={"./client",argv[1],curPid,NULL};

else if(pid==0)
{
    if(execvp("./client",arguments)==-1)
    {
        perror("Failed To Execute 'client.c' Program");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```